# Service still available from outside the controller AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've build a service for provide the posibility to add markers to google maps intance, but this only happens when I'm inside a particular controller using the ngRoute service. The issue is that when I first load the app my service doesn't work outside the controller where it is injected, when I switch to the controller where it is injected and it works, but when I go backward to the controller where it isn't injected my service works! Where is the problem here?

**ngRoute config**

```
var climbingApp = angular.module('climbingApp', ['ngRoute'], 
 function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        controller: 'Main'
    });

    $routeProvider.when ('/newSector', {
        templateUrl: 'app/templates/newSector.html',
        controller: 'addSector'
    });
});
```

**Controllers**

```
    function addSector($scope, Markers) {

        Markers.addListener( function ( e ){
                $scope.lat = e.latLng.lat();
            $scope.lng = e.latLng.lng();
        });

    }

    function Main ($scope) {
           $scope.initLocation = {
                   lat: -54.798112,
                   lng: -68.303375
           };

    }
```

**Service**

```
climbingApp.factory('Markers', function($rootScope){
    return {
        addListener: function( callback ) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(
                map,
                'click',
                 function( e ) {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: e.latLng,
                        map: map
                    });

                    $rootScope.$apply( function(){ callback( e ); });
                }
            );
        }
    }
});
```

I guess the problem is that the listener is still atached to the map instance, but how could I destroy it?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to be more specific but make sure your controller is actually being destroyed also make sure you should be using a factory here... I don't find many uses for them as they aren't singletons which means a new instance of your factory is injected into every single controller i.e. if your factory houses data and you inject it into two different controllers the data would be different for both of them.  A service on the other hand is a singleton and has the opposite effect.  That may be what you're seeing.

Comment: Don't you define services by using the .factory method? How could I make sure that the controller is being destroyed?

Comment: Inside you're controller you can specify an on destroy method and you can check to see if that is being triggered: $scope.$on('$destroy',function(){ alert('controller destroyed') });